# Why do some people state that 'Zero is not a number'?

Tags: math-history

Every [now](https://web.archive.org/web/20171110142123/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57186.html) and [then](https://thinkingtobelieve.com/2011/06/02/is-zero-a-number/) I read about people who wonder whether zero is a number. It never occurred to me to question this, so I checked the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(number)) which, when talking about the [Rules of Brahmagupta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(number)#Rules_of_Brahmagupta) explains

> In saying zero divided by zero is zero, Brahmagupta differs from the modern position. Mathematicians normally do not assign a value to this, whereas computers and calculators sometimes assign NaN, which means "not a number."

I did consider whether this difference in position may be the reason why some people state that "Zero is not a number".

Comment: Related: (In the sense that your question may be an answer to it, or vice-versa) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12323/whats-the-hard-part-of-zero

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few distinctions:

In your first link, the discussion is regarding whether $0$ is a *natural* number, not that it is/isn't a number.

Your second link is predicated upon fairly weak, insubstantial first-year undergraduate arguments that can be dispelled with a [more rigorous construction of numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers). I also question any blog that concludes a logical argument with "what's your opinion?" (I'd also question the veracity of a mathematical argument coming from a theological blog -- in the same way that I would question the veracity of a monetary policy argument coming from a sports blog).

Finally, the $0/0 = 0$ argument is considered non-standard. That most mathematicians define $0/0 = \text{NaN}$ is not the same as $0 = \text{NaN}$ because these are competing definitions.

So, in short, people often claim "zero is not a number" because they lack the background to understand the formal, rigorous definitions of the number system.

Comment: Strictly speaking "NaN" is distinct from "is not defined". NaN comes from the specification for floating point values, which computers generally use as an approximation of the real numbers. NaN is a well defined value (actually several, as there are distinct flavors of NaN) with specific properties (such as being unequal to all floating point values, including itself).

Comment: Yeah, I was a little loose on my terminology there, overloading NaN with both a computer science definition and an unrelated "not a defined number" definition.

Comment: Yeah, that's part of the distinction I'm trying to make--the *expression* 0/0 has no defined value, i.e., the division operation is not defined on those arguments in the same way that division by "cucumber" is not defined. There is nothing denoted by 0/0 to *be* a number or not.

Comment: Division by cucumber clearly leads to salad.