# Is $1$ a subset of $\{1\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the number $1$ a subset of the set $\{1\}$ just as $\{1\}$ is a subset of the set $\{\{1\}\}$? I'm a little bit confused because $1$ is an `element` not a `set`...

Comment: $\{1\}$ is also an element of $\{\{1\}\}$, not a subset. Suppose you have $A = \{1,2,3\}$, we say $2$ is an element of $A$ (and we write $2 \in A$), but we say $\{2\}$ is a subset of $A$ (and we write $\{2\} \subseteq A$), because _every element of $\{2\}$ is in $A$_.

Comment: `{1}` isn't a subset of `{{1}}`, unless you are working in an ill-founded set theory and have defined `1` in a way such that `1 = {1}`.

Comment: see [**here**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064663/x-in-x-or-not/1064730#1064730]), and [**here**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218925/what-is-the-difference-between-the-relations-in-and-subseteq/1218933#1218933), and [**here**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271174/is-this-element-a-subset-of-set-a/1271182#1271182).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

$1$ is an element of $\{1\}$, $\{1\}$ is a subset of $\{1\}$, $\{1\}$ is an element of $\{\{1\}\}$ and $\{\{1\}\}$ is a subset of $\{\{1\}\}$.

Comment: No flaws in your logic, but that doesn't really answer the question...

Comment: @Dennis: great !! Therefore propose a real answer !

Comment: I didn't mean this is a bad way. It's just not immediately obvious why the fact that $1$ is an element of $\{1\}$ would imply that it cannot be a subset.

Comment: My last comment was absolutely not a reproach. I just incited you to make an answer that would be more helpful for the OP :-)

Comment: @idm Is {1} a subset of {{1}}?

Comment: no, an element !

Answer (score 15):

$1$ is generally not a subset of $\{1\}$, since $1$ is a natural number (or a real number, or whatever) and not a set. These objects are of two different types.

But there is something to be said here. We can *represent* numbers using sets. We can declare that $0$ is $\varnothing$, and that $1=\{0\}$ or $\{\varnothing\}$, and that $2=\{0,1\}$ and so on. Then a number *is* a set.

Still that doesn't mean that $1\subseteq\{1\}$. This would very much depend on the representation of $1$ as a set.

So while "working mathematics" is typed (meaning the type of objects matters), we can also work in an untyped environment, where everything has the same type (for example, everything is a set).

Comment: It looks very unusual how a set could actually be named by a single number that way, so I'd like to see some sources showing someone actually using such notation.

Comment: @mathh: That's the usual way of defining natural number in axiomatic set theory, since the resulting set is the one provided by the Axiom of Infinity. See [Set-theoretic definition of natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers "Set-theoretic definition of natural numbers - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia")

Comment: Using this representation of numbers, we would, however, have $1\subset 2$. Weird, but true.

Comment: Seeing how several people gave similar answers, the downvote feels kinda personal.

Answer (score 9):

As @AsafKaragila already said, you *can* define natural numbers as sets. In fact, in most axiomatic set theories, that's the *only* way of defining numbers, since every element of a set is a set.

As for your specific question, suppose that $1\subset\{1\}$. This leaves us with two options:

1. $1=\emptyset$ and the inclusion trivially holds.
2. $1\neq\emptyset$. Since $\{1\}$ has only two subsets, $1=\{1\}$.

Option 1 is possible, since identifying $1$ with the empty set is perfectly valid, but it's much more natural to identify $0$ with the empty set.

Option 2 just "looks wrong", but in elementary set theory, we can't really make any statements beyond that. In any axiomatic set theory that includes the [Axiom of Regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity), $1=\{1\}$ is false since $x\notin x$ for every set $x$.

Answer (score 8):

$1 \in \{1\}$

$\{1\} \subseteq \{1\}$

As you said, 1 is an element of $\{1\}$, not a set.

Answer (score 3):

On both the cases, 1 is element of {1} & {1} is element of {{1}}.
                   i.e.  1 ∈{1} & 
                        {1}∈{{1}}

And, in case of subset, {1} is subset of {1}. 
                   i.e. {1}⊆{1}

Answer (score 3):

**No**. Every natural number is [constructed based on *set theory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Constructions_based_on_set_theory). Because of that every natural number is a *set*. To be more general, because we build up the whole mathematics from set theory, we can say that in mathematics everything is a set. The construcion is the following.

- $0 = \emptyset$
- $1 = \{ 0 \} = \{ \emptyset \}$
- $2 = \{0, 1 \} = \{ 0, \{0\} \} = \{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \}$
- and so on.

Since $1 = \{ 0 \} = \{ \emptyset \}$ and $\{1\} = \{ \{ 0 \} \} = \{ \{ \emptyset \} \}$ and the subsets of $\{ 1 \}$ are $\wp\left( \{ 1 \}\right) = \wp\left(\{ \{ \emptyset \} \}\right)=\{\emptyset,\{ \{ \emptyset \} \}\}$ we can say that $ \{ \emptyset \} \notin \wp\left(\{1\}\right) $ so $\{ \emptyset \} \not\subseteq \{ \{ \emptyset \} \}$ and that is why $1 \not\subseteq \{1\}$.

On the other hand, because we have an [*axiom of extensionality*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) and since we have [*element predicate*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)), the fact that $\{ 1 \}$ contains $1$ exactly means that $1 \in \{1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is ambiguous but not uncommon to see a set with a single member referred to as simply that member, in contexts where the author would expect the reader to understand that only sets are under discussion.

Comment: An unfortunate abuse of notation. I tried to have my alg. top. professor to stop doing it, but it didn't work. I kept having this twitch whenever it happened... :P

Comment: I know that feeling.  There are a couple of things that "working mathematicians" sometimes do that give set theorists the creeps... :)