# Is this element a subset of set A?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A$ be the set $\{\propto,\{1,\propto\},\{3\},\{\{1,3\}\},3\}$.
>   The statement "$\{1,\propto\}\subseteq A$" is false.

(Taken from [A Concise Introduction to Pure Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439835985))

But I think this is true as can see $\{1,\propto\}$ as being a subset of $A$ ?

Comment: it should have been $(1,\alpha) \in A$

Comment: The statement $\{1,\propto\}\subseteq A$ is indeed false. I think you have a misconception between element ($\{1,\propto\}\in A$ is true) and subset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. $\{1, \propto\}$ is an *element* of $A$, but not a *subset* of $A$. If it was a subset, every element of it, i.e. both $1$ and $\propto$, would have to be elements of $A$.

$\propto$ is an element of a, but $1$ is not. It is only contained in an element (this element is $\{1,\propto\}$ and is, by chance, also a set) so

$$1 \notin A \Rightarrow \{1,\propto\} \not\subset A$$

On the other hand, $\{3\}$ is both an element of $A$ (the third one in your list) *and* a subset of $A$, because all elements of $\{3\}$ (the only one being $3$) are also an element of $A$ ($3$ is the fifth in your list)

To help clarify, here are the *elements* of $A$:

$$\propto\\ \{1,\propto\}\\ \{3\}\\\{\{1,3\}\}\\ 3$$

The *subsets* of $A$ are sets consisting of elements of $A$, i.e.

$$\emptyset\\
\{\propto\}\\
\{\{1,\propto\}\}\\
\{\{3\}\}\\
\{\{\{1,3\}\}\}\\
\{3\}\\
\{\propto, \{1,\propto\}\}\\
\ldots\\
\{\{3\},3\}\\
\ldots\\
\{\propto, \{1,\propto\}, \{3\}, \{\{1,3\}\}, 3\} = A$$

Comment: if 1 is included as an element of A then {1,∝} is a subset of A ?

Comment: @blue-sky If both, $1$ and $\propto$ were elements of $A$, then $\{1,\propto\}$ was a subset of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

"element" and "subset"; see [$x\in \{\{\{x\}\}\}$ or not?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064663/x-in-x-or-not/1064730#1064730])
$\{1,\propto\}\subseteq A$ is false.
$\{\{1,\propto\}\}\subseteq A$ is true.
$\{1,\propto\}\in A$ is true.

Comment: Specially I think *Hagen von Eitzen*'s answer and *my* answer (user 1) can help.

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218925/what-is-the-difference-between-the-relations-in-and-subseteq?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

No. $\{1,\alpha\}$ is a subset of $A$, if all its elements (namely $1, \alpha$) are elements of $A$, so we have to check whether $1 \in A$ and $\alpha \in A$. The elements of $A$ are

> (1) $\alpha$, (2) $\{1,\alpha\}$, (3) $\{3\}$ and (4) $\bigl\{\{1,3\}, 3\bigr\}$

So, $\alpha \in A$ ($\alpha$ is No. 1 in our list above, but $1 \not\in A$. So, as not all elements of $\{1,\alpha\}$ are elements of $A$, we have $\{1,\alpha\} \not\subseteq A$.

Note that $\{1,\alpha\}$ is an elements of $A$ (no. 2 above), but this has nothing to do with it being a subset.

Comment: NB the actual symbol used in the question is `\propto`, not `\alpha`.

Answer (score 0):

No, $\{1,\propto\}$ is not a subset of $A$.

In order for $S$ to be a subset of $A$, it must be true that *every* element of $S$ is also an element of $A$. In your case, $1$ is an element of $\{1,\propto\}$, but $1$ is not an element of $A$, so $\{1,\propto\}$ is not a subset of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a subset, then $1$ would had to be an element of $A$, but it isn't. There's only a set which contains $1$, which is an element of $A$, but not $1$ itself. However, {1,∝} is an element of $A$.